# Parser XML Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows, parsing, windows-phone

I am trying to parse xml for windows phone web in C # and failed to find the result to obtain the data, the problem is in how I ask

```
var rssFeed = XElement.Parse(response);
var channel = rssFeed.Descendants("feed");
var items = (from item in channel.Elements("entry") select new ItemsLoad
```

I can not find a way to get results, any ideas? Help please!

```
public class ItemsLoad
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PubDate { get; set; }

    public static List<ItemsLoad> GetElements(string response)
    {
        var rssFeed = XElement.Parse(response);
        var channel = rssFeed.Descendants("feed");
        var items = (from item in channel.Elements("entry")
            select new ItemsLoad
            {
                Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                Link = item.Element("link").Value,
                Description = item.Element("summary").Value,
                PubDate = item.Element("published").Value
            });
    return items.ToList();
}
```

my full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
   <id>index.xml</id>
   <title>Last</title>
   <updated>2014-10-13T06:17:44+00:00</updated>
   <author>
      <name>John</name>
      <email>John dot com</email>
      <uri>this-is-test.com</uri>
   </author>
   <entry>
      <id>213213</id>
      <published>2014-09-17T10:45:36+00:00</published>
      <title xml:lang="en">Test</title>
      <summary xml:lang="en">Test xml windows phone</summary>
      <link rel="alternate"
            type="text/html"
            href="http://www"
            title="story">
         <media:content>
            <media:thumbnail url="tese.jpg"
                             width="106"
                             height="60">
               <img alt="test"
                    width="106"
                    height="60"
                    src="test.jpg"/>
            </media:thumbnail>
            <media:thumbnail url="test.jpg"
                             width="144"
                             height="81">
               <img alt="test"
                    width="144"
                    height="81"
                    src="test.jpg"/>
            </media:thumbnail>
         </media:content>
      </link>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

this is the xml file

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues on your code:

1. After parsing the XML, `feed` is already the current node, so `rssFeed.Descendants("feed")` won't find anything
2. The elements have a namespace (the `xmlns="..."` on `feed`), you need to provide it when parsing the nodes:

   ```
   public static List<ItemsLoad> GetElements(string response)
   {
       const string Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

       var rssFeed = XElement.Parse(response);

       var items = (from item in rssFeed.Elements(XName.Get("entry", Namespace))
           select new ItemsLoad
           {
               Title = item.Element(XName.Get("title", Namespace)).Value,
               Link = item.Element(XName.Get("link", Namespace)).Value,
               Description = item.Element(XName.Get("summary", Namespace)).Value,
               PubDate = item.Element(XName.Get("published", Namespace)).Value
           });
       return items.ToList();
   }
   ```